# Passing system variable to Apache stopped working

Tags: apache, environment-variables, mod-headers

We rebooted one of our servers over the weekend and now Apache won't pass through the host name - not sure whats wrong. Here's my config:

```
LoadModule                          headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule                          env_module modules/mod_env.so

<IfModule headers_module>
    <IfModule env_module>
        PassEnv                     HOSTNAME
        Header                      always set X-Host-Name "%{HOSTNAME}e"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I am running as a user other than root. I am able to execute `sudo -u websrv "printenv"` and the value for HOSTNAME appears appropriately.

Not sure whats going on

Comment: You are probably exporting `HOSTNAME` in a *~/.bashrc* or similar shell script but starting your web server in a manner that does not source that script.

Comment: this was working before the reboot so I'm not sure it's that

Comment: I've been programming computers for more than four decades. You would be amazed how often I have personally, or seen someone else, make a change that only manifests as a problem man days, or even weeks, later when the system is rebooted or an app is restarted. I am 100% certain you made a change that had unintended side-effects which only surfaced when you did the reboot. Two questions: a) where are you setting HOSTNAME and b) how are you launching the web server?

Comment: ${HOSTNAME} is a system-level variable, I wasn't setting it anywhere. Combination of systemd and apachectl.

Comment: So I did a bit more digging and it appears that the variable isn't being set when systemd is used, but if apachectl is used everything is fine. Not sure why, but it doesn't matter I suppose. I added ```Environment=HOSTNAME=<hostname>``` to the systemd unit and it's fine.